# PHP Ajax fine uploader not uploading files when filename with single quotes on some server

Tags: php, ajax, file-upload

I am using php mysql.Implemented ajax fine uploader for file upload process.Its working fine.

Problem came when filename with single quotes like( venk'spicture.jpeg ) not uploaded to server.Its working fine in Local development server .In live server its not working. I tracked to save the request details in server with below code

```
$file = 'update-data.txt';
$fh = fopen($file, 'a+') or die("can't open file");
$content='------------ The Start ------------'."\r\n";
$content.='$_FILES'." \n";
$content.=print_r($_FILES,true)."  \r\n";
$content.='$_REQUEST'." \n";
$content.=print_r($_REQUEST,true)."  \r\n";
$content.='$_POST'." \n";
$content.=print_r($_POST,true)."  \r\n";
$content.='$_SESSION'." \n";
$content.=print_r($_SESSION,true)."  \r\n";
$content.='Error'." \n";
$content.=$error."  \r\n";

fwrite($fh, $content);
fclose($fh);
```

There was no post data,request data or session data or file data.Simply server ignored the file process. In client side Fine uploader progressing   bar shows file uploaded to 100 %.There was error indicated JSON response problem in client side.In server side i checked,
there was no details saved in those 'update-data.txt' file.

Same file removed the quotes Like (venkspicture.jpeg) uploaded perfectly. All request,post,session,file data saved in 'update-data.txt'.

Server Details:

PHP Version 5.2.17,Linux,
magic_quotes_gpc: on,
magic_quotes_runtime: off,
Configure Command:,

```
'./configure' '--enable-bcmath' '--enable-calendar' '--enable-ftp' '--enable-gd-native-ttf' '--enable-libxml' '--enable-magic-quotes' '--enable-mbstring' '--enable-pdo=shared' '--enable-sockets' '--enable-zip' '--prefix=/usr' '--with-curl=/opt/curlssl/' '--with-freetype-dir=/usr' '--with-gd' '--with-imap=/opt/php_with_imap_client/' '--with-imap-ssl=/usr' '--with-jpeg-dir=/usr' '--with-kerberos' '--with-libdir=lib64' '--with-libxml-dir=/opt/xml2/' '--with-mcrypt=/opt/libmcrypt/' '--with-mhash=/opt/mhash/' '--with-mysql=/usr' '--with-mysql-sock=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' '--with-openssl=/usr' '--with-openssl-dir=/usr' '--with-pcre-regex=/opt/pcre' '--with-pdo-mysql=shared' '--with-pdo-sqlite=shared' '--with-pic' '--with-png-dir=/usr' '--with-sqlite=shared' '--with-ttf' '--with-xpm-dir=/usr' '--with-zlib' '--with-zlib-dir=/usr'
```

Can you please help me whats wrong with the server details..

Comment: `magic_quotes_gpc: on` – most likely that’s the problem. It makes `'` become `\'`, and a backslash has no place being in a file name. (You should _check_ and if necessary _sanitize_ the file name anyway, otherwise you have a potential security hole.)

Comment: Thank you for replied.In local previously **magic_quotes_gpc = off**. I upload filename with single quotes it uploaded perfectly.I just turn on the **magic_quotes_gpc = on** in local system.After restart, I upload files single quoted on file name.Its uploaded in local development server as before.So magic quotes gpc is not a problem i think..

Comment: I am also facing same problem . I'll post its reply after getting the solution. Thanks. If you have any solution for it , let me know.